# c# validating chat: validate if list contains container with my message

Tags: ranorex

I am trying to validate chat, but don't want to do it by index. Instead I want to iterate through every item in the list and find my message. How can I do that?

```
Container type: run
Text: message
```

Tree looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWrzt.png)

Example I found earlier:

```
var match = myList
    .FirstOrDefault(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(myString));

if(match != null)
    //Do stuff
```

I am a beginner and struggling to understand how to do this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Note: I am using ranorex if this helps anyone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a repo item which will find the message:

1. Use Ranorex spy to create a repo item which will find the desired
   message.
2. In the Ranorex spy, switch to the path editor.
3. Find the attribute (i.e. @text) containing the expected message and check it.
4. Replace the value with a variable.

Drag the created repo item in a recording and bind the variable to the expected message content.

No code!

Hope this helps.

I suggest you watch the [Ranorex screencasts](https://www.ranorex.com/support/screencasts.html) especially the ones explaining how to use the XPath.  You will save lot of time.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot :) understood how to use it.

Comment: Thanks.  I would add that you should consider using a repository variable naming convention since I once had a name collision between a recording variable name and a repository variable with the same name (used by the recording). You can prefix your repository with 'r_' or something equivalent to help differentiate easily between recording variable and repository variable when doing your bindings.